# Resize Image To Size of Other Image Python PIL

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library, simplecv

I have one image, and I have another image that I would like to resize to the size of the first image in python. I've attempted this in many different ways, all resulting in failure. How can I do this?

Some failed methods:

**.thumbnail(),** only works for a PIL image, which means it can't interact with SimpleCV images later on in the program

**.resize()**, when I used the arguments, it resulted in the error.

Alternate Solution:

Setting camera resolution, though I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Show us some code that failed please.

Comment: @trs did that help?

Comment: show the code with the error that gives you error in resize() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the camera was the only object with an unknown size, I was able to set it like the following:

```
cam = camera(prop_set ={'width':width, height:'height'})
```